# Freestyle Renders Triangles but the original Mesh are Quads

Tags: rendering, freestyle, svg

I'm doing a freestyle render of [this model](https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-print-models/art/sculptures/lion-of-nemea) because I want the SVG. But the result difers from the original mesh. Freestyle adds in between lines on every quad making it triangles. I've been trying to change the crease angle but anything below 180° loses a lot of lines.

How can I render a SVG wireframe that's close to the original one?

Original Mesh - Mostly Quads

[image]

Freestlye SVG Render - Added lines, mostly tris

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hard to test without having your model, but how about making the Line Set capture _only_ Freestyle-marked edges, and marking all edges as Freestyle?

Comment: It worked, thank you so much Robin!